# About google adwords conversions

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

So I'm stuck with problem: I have created conversion and added snippet inside body tag. Problem is:

1. I don't quite understand, in my developer console, in section
   "Network" I see a conversion request, but there are 4 of them and
   only one is 200 OK, others are 302. Is this normal?
2. Regarding click conversions. I have some kind of contact form (not
   plugin), it does ajax request to my server (sending contact form
   data). And in $.ajax's "success" section I added call of conversion
   click function. It does same as page load conversion: makes 4
   request, 3 are 302, 1 is 200.

Is it normal? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Tag Assistant chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) to debug tags, it has its flaws but can usually be trusted.

But in general:

1. Yes, perfectly normal. What is actually happening here is that Google uses the 302 to log the actual conversion, but then redirects you to serve the pixel (or script) to save bandwidth.
2. Same thing. But you might want to setup a different conversion label here, so you can track both conversions separately.

You might also benefit from using Google Analytics, which will give you a bunch more data about user behavior and help debug tag problems.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm also a bit confused about how can I track those conversion? Google adwords seems not tracking those conversions o_o
At least I was spamming like 10 contact form sumbits, and dashboard says there were 0 conversion on that day. Should I just remake conversions? Make like 2 conversions (one for page-load and one for contact form submits) ?

Comment: That could be from a huge number of factors. Bear in mind that conversion data is not real-time, and you should check on the day after.
If you still cannot see conversions, debug it bottom up: check GTM live debug to see if the tag is firing and with the desired conversion label, then check tag assistant, than look for it on GAW.